# Why is elasticsearch only returning 5 highlights for a field with an array of values that have more matches based on the query?

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-highlight

To demonstrate the issue here is a dynamically created index with single document:

```
PUT /test_highlight_number/_doc/1 
{ 
   "id": 1,
   "names": ["john 1","john 2", "john 3", "john 4", "john 5", "john 6", "john 7", "john 8"]
}
```

When I run the following search

```
GET /test_highlight_number/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "names": {
        "query": "john"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "names": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I get a response that only highlights 5 of the 8 matching names in the **highlight** key of **hits**. Is there a way to tell elasticsearch to return all highlights for a field based on the query?

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.55034834,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_highlight_number",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.55034834,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "names" : [
            "john 1",
            "john 2",
            "john 3",
            "john 4",
            "john 5",
            "john 6",
            "john 7",
            "john 8"
          ]
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "names" : [
            "<em>john</em> 1",
            "<em>john</em> 2",
            "<em>john</em> 3",
            "<em>john</em> 4",
            "<em>john</em> 5"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not specified number_of_fragments parameter. It is default to `5`. You should read [highlighting settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html#highlighting-settings) part.

If you want to retrieve all the fragments that match the query. Your query should be like this:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "names": {
        "query": "john"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "names": {
        "number_of_fragments": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```